# How to filter NSFetchedResultsController with relationship - Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display data in a table view. I have 2 objects, Client, and Formula. A `Client` can have many `Formulas` but a Formula can have just one `Client`, so a one-to-many relationship. When I tap on a certain `Client` in a `table view cell`, I want to only be seeing formulas related to that client, but when I tap on other cells, those contain the same Formula objects, so it's not filtering. I know I need to use a predicate to filter the `fetch request`, but I do not know where to start.

This is the `fetchedResultsController` I have set up.

```
let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Formula> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Formula> = Formula.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

    return NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: "date", cacheName: nil)
}()
```

So somewhere in there, I have to add `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: ...)` but I do not know what to enter inside that initializer.

Comment: `format: "theAttributeOfFormulaThatLinksItToAClient.anAttributedOfClientThatCanIdentifiyIt == %@", theClientSelectedIDValueThatCanIdentifyIt`. We need to see your model, but that's more or less what to do.

Comment: My model is a .datamodeld file

Comment: @Larme This is what I've tried: `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "client.formulas == %@", CVARARG)` . I don't know what to put for the CVarArg.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your question, you need to add a predicate to your fetch request to filter the fetched objects. In that predicate you need to use reverse relationship from `Formula` to `Client`. Like so:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentClient == %@", parentClient)
```